# Import android project into new workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, import, workbench

How can I import an old Project into my new workspace with a new installed version
of eclipse?

Just one not the complete workspace

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the folder into your Workspace folder, and go to the little project exporer on the left and import it.  That's about it.

Answer (score 1):

file -> import -> projects menu should let you do what you need then just follow the wizard.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to file menu ->inport
2. Select General-> Existing projects into workspace
   3, Browse the project folder
3. If you want copy the project into workspace enable the checkmark
4. Finish

Answer (score 0):

Create a project with the same name of the old project. Then replace all the files on its directory.